# Adding foreign key constraint to associative entity

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, many-to-many, constraints, composite-key

I have 3 tables:
1) SERVICE_REQUESTS (Parent)

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICE_REQUESTS(
service_id           NUMBER (7)    NOT NULL,
serial_number        NUMBER (10)   NOT NULL,
service_date         DATE          NOT NULL,
service_description  VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
hourly_rate          NUMBER(5,2)   NOT NULL,
customer_id          NUMBER  (5)   NOT NULL,
employee_id          NUMBER  (3)   NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT service_request_pk PRIMARY KEY(service_id, serial_number));
```

2) SERVICE_PARTS (Associative Entity to solve M:M relationship)

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICE_PARTS(
service_id           NUMBER  (7)   NOT NULL,
part_id              NUMBER (10)   NOT NULL,
quantity             NUMBER  (4)   NOT NULL,
unit_cost            NUMBER(7,2)   NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT service_part_pk PRIMARY KEY(service_id, part_id));
```

3) PARTS (Parent)

```
CREATE TABLE PARTS(
part_id              NUMBER (10)   NOT NULL,
part_description     VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
cost                  NUMBER(7,2)   NOT NULL,
quantity_on_hand     NUMBER  (5)   NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT part_pk PRIMARY KEY(part_id));
```

I've created a foreign key constraint from `SERVICE_PARTS` to `PARTS` with the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE service_parts
  ADD CONSTRAINT service_parts_part_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (part_id)
      REFERENCES parts(part_id);
```

Now I'm trying to create a foreign key constraint from `SERVICE_PARTS` to `SERVICE_REQUESTS` using the follow statement:

```
ALTER TABLE service_parts
  ADD CONSTRAINT service_parts_service_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (service_id)
      REFERENCES service_requests(service_id);
```

But I get the following error: `ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list`. Why does it allow a constraint to be added for the part_id but not the service_id?

I've attached my ER Diagram for visual clarification:
[image]

Comment: The diagram and text in your question conflict. The diagram has a `SERVICE_REQUEST` table with primary key of `service_id`, but the text description has the table name as `SERVICE_REQUESTS` with a primary key of `(service_id, serial_number)`. So which is correct? Please update either the diagram or the text.

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for bringing that up. The program that we use in class hides the identifying primary keys. The `|` in the `>|----` attached to the right side of the `SERVICE_REQUEST` table means that the primary key in the `EQUIPMENT` table is also being used as primary key / foreign key in the `SERVICE_REQUEST` table. Likewise with the `SERVICE_PART` table, it has 2 `>|--` & `--|<` coming from the `SERVICE_REQUEST` entity and the `PART` entity. This means that the primary in the `SERVICE_PART` table are being identified by the `SERVICE_REQUEST` and `PART` entity.

Answer (score 1):

If the primary key of the `service_requests` table is `service_id, serial_number`, your M:M mapping table would need to include both elements of the primary key.  The definition of the primary key implies that you can have many rows with the same `service_id` but different `serial_number` values.  If your mapping table doesn't contain both elements of the key, you wouldn't be able to figure out which particular row in `service_requests` was mapped to any particular row in `service_parts`.

Your mapping table definition would need to be

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICE_PARTS(
service_id           NUMBER  (7)   NOT NULL,
serial_number        NUMBER (10)   NOT NULL,
part_id              NUMBER (10)   NOT NULL,
quantity             NUMBER  (4)   NOT NULL,
unit_cost            NUMBER(7,2)   NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT service_part_pk PRIMARY KEY(service_id, serial_number, part_id));
```

and then your foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE service_parts
  ADD CONSTRAINT service_parts_service_id_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (service_id, serial_number)
      REFERENCES service_requests(service_id, serial_number);
```

Alternately, if we believe that your mapping table is correct, which would imply that `service_id` was the key for `service_requests`, then the definition of `service_requests` would be

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICE_REQUESTS(
service_id           NUMBER (7)    NOT NULL,
serial_number        NUMBER (10)   NOT NULL,
service_date         DATE          NOT NULL,
service_description  VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
hourly_rate          NUMBER(5,2)   NOT NULL,
customer_id          NUMBER  (5)   NOT NULL,
employee_id          NUMBER  (3)   NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT service_request_pk PRIMARY KEY(service_id));
```

Then your mapping table and your foreign key definition would be correct as is.

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks again for your help. I've attached a picture this time to help explain this better. I assumed that I would have to have an identifying relationship from the `EQUIPMENT` table for my  `SERVICE_REQUESTS`. Am I wrong in doing so?

Comment: I'm not seeing an `equipment` table (I can't see the image you uploaded, probably blocked by my firewall).

Comment: The `EQUIPMENT` table has the following attributes: `serial_number, brand, model, equipment_type` and then there are 4 subtypes within the table. So the `serial_number` is the primary key and I've already referenced to it from the `SERVICE_REQUESTS` table. [ER Diagram Link](http://tinypic.com/r/1zvs5s7/8)

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key in table `SERVICE_REQUESTS`:

```
CONSTRAINT service_request_pk PRIMARY KEY(service_id, serial_number)
```

Such primary key can't guarantee, that your `service_id` value will be unique. Hence, you can't make reference only to this field from another table, because there is no way to determine, to which record you will refer. Your primary key in one table and foreign key in another have to be exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry, my `serial_number` is a foreign key to an equipment table which has to be unique. Let me attach my ER diagram to help illustrate this better.